# UINavigation Bar being set by a different controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar, title

What is happening in my app is that the user logs in and then the title of the controller becomes "Hello (Username)" and then the user presses a button and is pushed to a UITableViewController with the title: "Messages". After they select a message they are pushed to another UITableViewController, with the title "Message to (receiver)".

The problem is that when you press the back button on the 2nd UITableViewController that is titled "Message to (receiver), the title for the first UITableViewController becomes "Hello (Username)" instead of "Messages". This bug only happened when I updated to Xcode 6, and I have no idea what is causing it.

In ViewController 1  :

```
-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    UIBarButtonItem *_backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:nil action:nil];
    self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = _backButton;
    _backButton = nil; //This is to make the Back button on other viewController to read "Back"
}

-(void) viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.title = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Hello %@", self.userLoggedIn];
    //Hide backbutton
    [self.navigationItem setHidesBackButton:YES animated:NO];
}

- (IBAction)messages:(id)sender
{
    TableViewController *tableVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"checkForMessagesVC"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:tableVC animated:YES];
}
```

In UITableViewController 1 :

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    self.title = @"Messages";
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    ViewMessagesVC *viewMessagesVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"viewMessagesVC"];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewMessagesVC animated:YES];
}
```

One more thing is that in ViewController 1 the back button is hidden. Then when you go to TableViewController 1 the back button shows, but when you go to TableViewController 2 and then go back to TVC 1 the back button is hidden. (Even if you put [self.navigationItem setHidesBackButton:NO animated:NO]; in the TableViewController's viewDidLoad the back button still won't show)

Not sure what is causing this, the only thing that is happening are pushes through a navigation controller and pressing the back button. There are timers and other things happening in each controller, but nothing effecting the title. Any ideas?

Comment: That is odd I must admit. Have you tried moving the this line to viewWillAppear self.title = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Hello %@", self.userLoggedIn];

Comment: No luck, but nice idea. Any others?

Comment: I am not able to repro this bug using the code provided. How are you setting the title on the third view controller "Messages to (receiver)"?

Comment: Side note, you should be calling [super viewDidLoad] in your viewDidLoad methods.

Comment: I cannot reproduce it either! I will try and provide all the code to see what is causing it. The third view controller's title is being set in a viewDidLoad: self.title = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Messages to %@", self.receiver];

Comment: One more thing is that in ViewController 1 the back button is hidden. Then when you go to TableViewController 1 the back button shows, but when you go to TableViewController 2 and then go back to TVC 1 the back button is hidden.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So hopefully nobody else foolishly runs into this weird error. For some reason the code in my 2nd TableViewController:

```
- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden
{
    return YES;
}
```

caused the error